# Fifth root of unity pentagon proof

Tags: calculus, analysis

I am stuck at an exercise that refers to the fifth root of unity with the equation $z^5-1=0$. I showed in an exercise before that 1 and $x=\frac{1}{2}(h+i\sqrt{4-h^2})$ are possible solutions for the equation.

Now the exercise says that there are $1,x,x^2,x^3,x^4$ given as edges of a pentagon and one can show that the side lengths are all equal.
I tried it by looking at:

$|x^{k+1}-x^k| = |x^k(x-1)| = |x^k||x-1| = |x|^k|x-1|  $(for integers k) but I don't know how to go on :/

Note: We haven't introduced Pi and Eulers identity in our lectures yet, so were not allowed to use them here!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $x^5=1$ then $|x|^5=|x|^5=1$ so $|x|=1$.

Comment: does that hold for x out of complex numbers?

Comment: @Blue2001 Yes. You can prove $|wz|=|w||z|$ for complex numbers, by combining $|z|=\sqrt{z^\ast z}$ with $(wz)^\ast=w^\ast z^\ast$.

Comment: But how can I conclude from $|x|=1$ that the pentagon has equal sides?

Comment: @Blue2001 You already proved $|x^{k+1}-x^k|=|x|^k|x-1|$. Since $|x|^k=1$, the result is the same for all $k$.

Comment: +1 : nice argument.

Comment: thank you very much! ;)